# invalid character when extracting xmltype using select in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

So I wanted to extract using this code from an xml table :

```
        SELECT
        DATE, EXTRACT(xmltype(REQ_DETAILS),'/FormManagementVO/SectionsList/Section/BasicFormFields/FormField[FormFieldId="accountNum"]/FormFieldValue/text()').getStringVal()accountDB 
WHERE DATE = '2021-05-28'
```

and there was a condition at the end which is just to filter the date, but somehow in one given date,
I got an error like :

```
ORA-19202 : Error occured in xml processing
LPX-00217 : invalid character 8 (U+0008)
Error at line 1
ORA-06512 : at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
```

I have tried to use :

```
DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(REGEXP_REPLACE(EXTRACT(xmltype(REQ_DETAILS),'/FormManagementVO/SectionsList/Section/BasicFormFields/FormField[FormFieldId="ACC_NUMBER"]/FormFieldValue/text()').getStringVal(),'[^[:print:]]',''))
```

that said can skip the invalid character, but it's wont work. Because I'm pretty new into this, I thought by giving the extract an alias will do, assuming that I was wrong with the syntax like :

```
SEL DBMS_XMLGEN.COVERT(REGEXP_REPLACE(A.ACC_NUMBER,'[^[:print:]]',''))
FROM (
SEL EXTRACT(xmltype(REQ_DETAILS),'/FormManagementVO/SectionsList/Section/BasicFormFields/FormField[FormFieldId="ACC_NUMBER"]/FormFieldValue/text()').getStringVal() AS ACC_NUMBER
FROM xml_mytable
)
```

but still throwing the same error, what did I do wrong here?

Comment: How do you think we can help you to process some data without knowing that data? Please, provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: somehow I can't do that, because I was extracting from user server database, so I can only do was providing the query? is there any code just to simply ignore the character? I've found dbms_xmlgen and/or regexp, but it seems didnt work

Comment: You use `replace` on the result of `extract`, but error tells you that the problem is in deserialization. You need to process your*source* data in *some* way, but without actual data or more details it is not possible to advise

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide **a minimal reproducible example**:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your database and its version.

Comment: I see, I had to contact the user who owns this database then, because for some reason I can only do select query in oracle.